# Sass store selector in variable

Tags: css, sass

I am trying to save a selector in SASS for easier referencing later, however I get a syntax error.

Here's what I'm trying to do:

```
$icon:  [class*="icon"];
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to convert it to a string if you want to use it as a variable:

```
$icon: '[class*="icon"]';

#{$icon} {
    // stuff
}
```

Comment: Is there any "shorter" way , so I can write it something like $icon(#{$icon} doesn't really save much writing)?

Comment: Calling `unquote()` is unnecessary.

Comment: @user2204158 I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: @cimmanon i was asking if there's a shorter way to reference the variable, instead of "#{$icon}".

Comment: No, this is your only option.  Unless you'd rather use a mixin, but that would be even more verbose.